# Export Adobe Photoshop color table (.ACT) file as csv file

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, file-conversion

How do I export Adobe Photoshop color table (.ACT) files as csv files?

Answer (score 3):

Well, in photoshop you do not. But the file itself is just a list of 8bit binary rgb colors ([according to adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/#50577411_pgfId-1070626)). So converting that to a csv should be pretty trivial to do with say python for example, you could also do it with jsx but its a bit more involved.

Here is a quick python example (quickly tested on the run):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# act2csv.py quick script no warranties whatsoever
import struct
import csv

DATA = []

with open("test.act", "rb") as actFile:
    for _ in range(256):
        raw = actFile.read(3)
        color = struct.unpack("3B", raw)
        DATA.append(color)

with open('test.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvWriter.writerows(DATA)
```

Comment: As I'm very new to this, Can you Please suggest step by step process of this.

Comment: Please do not add things that are not answers in answer fields. Once you have more than 10 points in participation then you can run this as a comment until then no dice. This question is perhaps meant for me i presume. Well you put the python code in a file and run that file with python. It will then unpack test.act into a csv file. But if you can not use python then start at: https://www.learnpython.org/