# Save Color Table with RGB details in Excel format

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Here I’m writing you because I don’t find any satisfactory answer/process on internet regarding this. Please suggest me how can I save Color Table (256 colors) with RGB in Excel or CSV format. Please check attached image for your reference. I had tried to save the color palette in ACT format, but then it won’t solve my problem.

Please suggest some way to get the used RBGs details in excel, It will be great help for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export Adobe Photoshop color table (.ACT) file as csv file](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/90809/export-adobe-photoshop-color-table-act-file-as-csv-file) The fact that you dont like the answer its still the same question, i dont have excel so i cant do this for you, not that there is much point in redoing the work anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, since you can not run python, and i can not run excel, surely we can send you a script in another way. We can let the browser do it for you!

If you have the web page (you can find a live version of this **[HERE](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEKwNY)**):

```
<div id="page-wrapper">

    <h1>Adobe act to space separated values</h1>
    <p>
        Select a *.act file: 
        <input type="file" id="input">
    </p>
    <pre id="result"><pre>

</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
        var input = document.getElementById('input');
        var result = document.getElementById('result');

        input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
            var file = input.files[0];

      var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) { 
          var arr = reader.result;
          var dv = new DataView(arr, 0);
          data = "";
          for (var i = 0; i < (256*3)-3 ; i+=3){
              data += dv.getUint8(i)   + " ";
              data += dv.getUint8(i+1) + " ";
              data += dv.getUint8(i+2) + "\n";
          } 
                result.innerText = data;
          }
          reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);   
      });
}
```

Then once you upload a file to the browser it just spits out the result as a space separated list of 3 values per row. You can then copy paste that to excel (like i said i have no excel but there is a option to invoke the tokenizer with paste special).

**Added**: Made a slightly more usable version, with swatches as well as hexacodes for copy-pasting. This version can be found **[here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgVxMy)**

Comment: One has got to wonder what use it is to answer these kinds of questions if only one person seems to think they are relevant. :) But it was fun to do...